# How to Extract the Fields in Bigquery in Nested JSON

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following BigQuery :

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.payload") from mytable
```

It returns this result :

```
[
  {
    "productInfo": {
      "productId": "123",
      "productType": "Dolls"
     
    },
   
    "storefrontPricingList": [
      {
        "currentPrice": {
          "unitValue": {
            "currencyAmount": 10,
            "currencyUnit": "USD"
          },
          "currentValue": {
            "currencyAmount": 10,
            "currencyUnit": "USD"
          },
          "variableUnitValue": {
            "currencyAmount": 10,
            "currencyUnit": "USD"
          },
          "sellValue": {
            "currencyAmount": 10,
            "currencyUnit": "USD"
          },
          "type": "EA"
        },
        "currentPriceType": "OKAY"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i want to access theses attributes productInfo.productId , currentPrice.unitValue.currencyAmount.

How we can access these elements i tries couple of things but all giving me null :

Like

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.payload[0].productInfo.productId") from mytable

select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, "$.payload[0].storefrontPricingList[0]. currentPrice. unitValue. currencyAmount") from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
-- Declaring a bigQuery variable 
DECLARE json_data JSON DEFAULT (SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"payload": [{"productInfo": {"productId": "123","productType": "Dolls" },"storefrontPricingList": [{"currentPrice": {"unitValue": {"currencyAmount": 10,"currencyUnit": "USD"},"currentValue": {"currencyAmount": 10,"currencyUnit": "USD"},"variableUnitValue": {"currencyAmount": 10,"currencyUnit": "USD"},"sellValue": {"currencyAmount": 10,"currencyUnit": "USD"},"type": "EA"},"currentPriceType": "OKAY"}]}]}'));

-- Select statement for extraction
select ARRAY(
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.productInfo.productId') from UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_data,"$.payload"))payload
)extracted_productID,
 ARRAY(
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.storefrontPricingList[0].currentPrice.unitValue.currencyAmount') from UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_data,"$.payload"))payload
 )extracted_currencyAmount
```

Used combination of Array function and Json function for BQ.

Output:
[image]